# RESTful web service: How can I take this data without printing out the other

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, rest

I want to just take the data from menSize and its price but it keep printing out the womenSize eventhought it doesn't add anything in it.

Do I need to seperate menSize class and womenSize class or is there any way to fix it:

Here is my Getter and Setter of Shoes class:

private double menSize;

```
private double price; 

private double womenSize;
```

This is my ShoesController class:

@GetMapping("menshoes")
public List getMenShoes() {

```
    List<Shoes> menShoesList = new ArrayList<>(); // Create ArrayList holding men sizes
    while (true) {
        for (double i = 2; i <= 12; i += 0.5) { // set sizes : 2 , 2.5 ,... until 12
            Shoes shoe = new Shoes();
            shoe.setMenSize(i);
            shoe.setPrice(4); // Set price to $4
            menShoesList.add(shoe); // add size to ArrayList
        }
        return menShoesList;
    }
}

@GetMapping("womenshoes")
public List<Shoes> getWomenShoes() {
    List<Shoes> womenShoesList = new ArrayList<>(); // Create ArrayList holding women sizes
    while (true) {
        for (double i = 5; i <= 12; i += 0.5) { // set sizes : 5, 5.5 , ... until 12
            Shoes shoe2 = new Shoes();
            shoe2.setWomenSize(i);
            shoe2.setPrice(4); // Set price to $4
            womenShoesList.add(shoe2); // add size to ArrayList
        }
        return womenShoesList;
    }
}
```

The output when I search for localhost:8080/menshoes are (I just take 3 for examples):

[{"menSize":2.0,"price":"$4.00","womenSize":0.0},{"menSize":2.5,"price":"$4.00","womenSize":0.0},{"menSize":3.0,"price":"$4.00","womenSize":0.0}

Comment: I would highly recommend only having one type similar to what you suggested. Perhaps with an Overloaded constructor that applies the price, gender, etc. **NOTE: I AM A STUDENT AND WE HAVE NOT COVERED LISTS YET, THIS ANSWER IS BASED OFF CLASS FORMATTING/USE**

Comment: In reference to @Johnnes' suggestion; here is a link explaining what an enum is too in case you (like me XD) just learned through this example what they are. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Enum-in-Java

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 options: Either having 2 classes, one for each type of shoe
or defining the type inside your class and not having two sizes of which one is always empty. Since you have a limited amount of possible types I suggest you use an enum for modeling the type.

```
public enum ShoeType {
    MEN,
    WOMEN
}

public class Shoe {
    private ShoeType type;
    private double size;
    private double price;
    // getter, setter, constructor...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Example of this comment:**
"I would highly recommend only having one [class] type similar to what you suggested"

Default constructor

```
public class Shoes
{
    this(null, 0, 0);
}
```

Overloaded constructor

```
public class Shoes(String gender, double size, double price)
{
    this.gender = gender;
    this.size = size;
    this.price = price;
}
```